# Dropdown Menu change

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu

Hi guys I'm a newbie in web programming, and have a problem with my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#adminBox").parent().append("<span></span>");    
$("a.adlog:link").click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find("#adminBox").slideDown('fast').show();
    $(this).parent().hover(function() {
    }, function(){  
        $(this).parent().find("#adminBox").slideUp('slow'); //here i want to change...
    });
    }).hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("a.adlog:hover");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("a.adlog:hover");
});
});
```

I want to change how `("#adminBox").slideUp('slow')` is processed when `$("a.adlog:link")` is clicked.

Comment: can u paste  u r html and css code in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Bluesvega, **HOW** do you want this changed?  Describe the current behavior and the ***desired*** behavior in detail. Include pictures if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#adminBox").parent().append("<span></span>");   

$(".adlog").click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().find("#adminBox").slideDown('fast');
})

$(".adlog").parent().hover(function() {
    }, function(){  
        $(this).parent().find("#adminBox").slideUp('slow'); //here you want to change...
});


$(".adlog").hover(function() { 
        $(this).addClass("adlogHover");
    }, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("adlogHover");
});

});
```